# How does one vertically center a specific item within a LazyColumn of dynamic, variable-height items?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

Say I have a `LazyColumn` set up with an unknown number of items of different sizes. Like a list of messages within a conversation.

```kotlin
LazyColumn {
   items(…) { … }
}
```

How can one go about scrolling the lazy column to *vertically center* an item within the `LazyColumn`'s *visible content*?

[image]

I know we can scroll by index with [LazyListState.scrollToItem](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyListState#scrollToItem(kotlin.Int,kotlin.Int))
…but the variable height items make it hard to pre-calculate the required scroll offset. We can't know how much space all of the items will take without pre-composing the whole list.